# Passing additional parameters to Html.Partial in ASP.Net Core 2.0 Razor

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm looping through a list in my Model and sending the data to an Html.Partial.

I'd like to know if I can pass an additional string value that isn't in the indexed model. I want to use this partial in two separate spots on the same page but I need to differentiate the data target for some Javascript.

For example, the loop in my *View* currently looks like this:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Team.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.Partial("EmployeeTableRow", Model.Team[i])
}
```

and the *EmployeeTableRow* partial:

```
<tr data-target="[additional string variable]">
    <td>@Model.Fname</td>
    <td>@Model.Lname</td>
</tr>
```

The actual Model data contains a great deal more info that I'd rather not have to specifically define using `new {}` if possible.

Any help or links to duplicate questions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use ViewBag for this but you should try to minimize the use of it to keep your code clean.

```
    @Html.Partial("EmployeeTableRow", Model.Team[i])
    ViewBag.AdditionalString = "something"
------------------------------------------------------
    <tr data-target="@ViewBag.AdditionalString">
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I agree about keeping things like this to a minimum.